# Reading content of process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to read content of current process to find a pattern, I get a pointer to the base address by calling `GetModuleHandleA()`, and then want to loop through it and keep matching bytes but I don't know whats the max size that I can loop through?

I tried to read the size of the file and use the file size as max loop counter.

Following is the code that I wrote so far,

```
    const char buf[] = { 0x40, 0x35, 0x02, 0x00, 0x78, 0x00 };

    char ProcessFilePath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, ProcessFilePath, MAX_PATH);
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(ProcessFilePath,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return -1;
    LARGE_INTEGER size;
    GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &size);

    const unsigned char* lpImage = (unsigned char*)GetModuleHandleA(NULL);

    int maincounter = 0;
    int patternsize = sizeof(buf);
    for (int maincounter = 0; maincounter < size.LowPart; maincounter++)
    {
        printf("%02x", lpImage[maincounter]);
    }
```

How can I read all the process memory? What is the right way to determine the memory size of a process?
For clarification, I'm trying to read process memory and match sequence of bytes of function signature. The goal is to find where in the memory the function is located.

Thanks

Comment: Use the [ToolHelp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_toolhelp/) API for such information.

Comment: *"How can I read all the process memory?"* - This question and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77287870/1889329) you seem to be happy with do not match. Please provide a succinct problem description.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) to me. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish by scanning through your process' memory? You have to be *very* careful doing that, or you might run into protected/guarded memory pages that will cause unwanted side effects if you access them incorrectly.

Comment: I'm trying to match sequence of bytes to find a function signature.

Comment: If this is about functions, then it sounds like you're interested in regions of memory that are executable only. This is a different problem from *"read\[ing\] all the process memory"*.

Comment: How can I only get executable regions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @500 - Internal Server Error comment, I used the ToolHelp API and my problem is solved.
`MODULEENTRY32` has two member `modBaseSize` for the size and `modBaseAddr` for the address.

```
DWORD GetModuleBaseAddress() 
{ 
  
    MODULEENTRY32 me32  = { sizeof(MODULEENTRY32) }; 
    HANDLE hSnapshot    = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, GetCurrentProcessId()); 

    if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return 0; 
    }
        
    if (Module32First( hSnapshot, &me32 )) { 
        CloseHandle( hSnapshot );
        cout << me32.modBaseSize<< endl;
        cout << me32.modBaseAddr << endl; 
    }

    CloseHandle(hSnapshot); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: We are appreciate that you are satisfied with the help 500 - Internal Server Error provided. If your case has been solved, please help to mark answer and this will be beneficial to other community.